# How to hide "page loading"/"transferring data" indicators and spinners caused by loading a (hidden) iframe

Tags: browser, iframe, xmlhttprequest, chunked-encoding

Is there any way to suppress the spinners and "transferring data" indicators that browsers show when a web page is loading?

I'm loading a document into a hidden iframe that will take a long time (10's of minutes).  I don't want/need the user to be aware of this - it's just confusing to them to have the page look like it's still loading.  SO I'd like to be able to disable all of the "page loading" activity that browsers normally show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found a solution that will work for us.  Instead of loading the document into a hidden iframe, we're using the "htmlfile" object described here:
http://cometdaily.com/2007/11/18/ie-activexhtmlfile-transport-part-ii/

This solves the problem on IE platforms.  And on non-IE platforms, we can use XMLHttpRequest + CORS + chunk encoding.