# Is there a way to stop the loading circle in browsers?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, google-chrome, browser, loading

Imagine I have a flash mp3 player and when the page loads the player starts to play a song. So while flash is downloading the mp3 file the browser reports the page like it's still loading. Which I understand, there are still active downloads. But a client wants me to somehow tell the browser not to show this progress (like the circle in chrome) for the files the player downloads.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Post your code. Or would you rather I guess?

Comment: What code? It's a general question.

Comment: Then a general answer would be yes it is possible. :)

Comment: I'm asking how... If I ask how to make a link in HTML would you ask me for my code or you'll just explain about `<a..></a>` ? I don't need code, just a place to look, an explanation how to do it. I can implement it myself.

Comment: I asked you to post code because of what you were saying in your question does not match up to how it works. You said "So while flash is downloading the mp3 file the browser reports the page like it's still loading." When this is not a normal function. The browser will only report on the loading of the SWF itself and not what the SWF is loading. 
So either you assumed this is what happens or someone coded it explicitly to report to the browser the progress.

Comment: Sorry for not understanding you. Unfortunately I cannot post the code because it's a script which sells on codecanyon. I didn't know this is not the normal behavior and now, knowing this I will scan through the source and see if there's anything which does the reporting stuff. Thanks

Comment: What browser are you testing in?

Comment: Try it with FireFox and run the addon called HTTPfox this add on will tell you what the browser is loading at any given time. I just verified that chrome 14 does not give me a loading status when flash is loading data, only during loading of html objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar question was posted here:

[How to hide "page loading"/"transferring data" indicators and spinners caused by loading a (hidden) iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623361/how-to-hide-page-loading-transferring-data-indicators-and-spinners-caused-by)

with a solution that might work for you.