# Flash to ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, flash

I made a flash game that when he user finishes the game he clicks a button, WHICH sends him BACK to the ASPX file (this is needed to save DATA to a DB), then after it saves the info it reloads back to the SWF file.

When the user clicks this button is it shows a loading % in the corner of the browser.

What is the loading progress indicating?

Comment: Please provide more detail. The phrase "Flash to ASP.NET" makes no sense at all because the two have very little to do with each other.

Comment: Using Response.Redirect has nothing to do with Flash either. Please provide more concrete detail.

Comment: How are you redirecting/passing data to the aspx page?

Comment: using  getURL var tempURL = "mainmenu.aspx?fVar1="+userID+"&fVar2="+score+;

 getURL(tempURL, "_self", "POST");

Answer (score 0):

In Flash movie or effects ..etc are on the frames. When frame is finished movie is finished. Then at last frame you can call a function and you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Because it loads on hidden frame. Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623361/how-to-hide-page-loading-transferring-data-indicators-and-spinners-caused-by